# Android Widget doesn't update on app upgrade

Tags: android, widget, refresh

We are working on the new version of the app that includes UI level changes to the widget. The new widget height is 3 rows while the current widget height is of 2 rows. Now, when we upgrade the app, it doesn't refresh the widget if already enabled.

Can anyone please confirm if we are missing or ignoring anything that could be the resulting in a messy widget on application upgrade. We need the refreshed widget enabled as soon as the app is upgraded.

Please note that the widget works fine if the user removes and adds it again post app upgrade.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the meta-data (appwidget-provider) file of the widget?

Comment: Hey, I would be able to do that in next hour. Is there anything specific that you can point me to? I can at least start looking into that. thanks for your comment

Comment: actually there one thing I want to check in the meta file, the value of `android:updatePeriodMillis` **&** to make sure you have registered `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` filter in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5400000" 
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" />

Comment: <receiver
            android:name=".WordWidget"
            android:label="@string/widget_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.xxxx.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_word" />
        </receiver>

Comment: are you aware that the widget is updating each 90 minutes?

Comment: yes, that is fine per our requirements

Comment: The problem is that on app upgrade, the widget gets removed from a few devices..and works fine with an updated widget on others

Comment: Also, if that helps.. we are compiling in 4.2 SDK

Comment: so far so good but should I be aware of anything unusual you're doing on `onUpdate` function that may cause your widget to close? I am afraid your code is crashing somewhere on the update function which is the reason why you're losing your widget .

Comment: We just got one line here: WordWidget.CONTEXT = context;

not doing anything else here..

Comment: for the sake of the argument what would happen if you comment this line?

Comment: ***I wanted to move to chat but your reputation is no allowing me do so***

Comment: just doing that... are you available on skype or anywhere..would make this little easier :)

Comment: I would love to do so but I am in the office right now :) I will contact you later on and I hope by then you would be already found your problem.

Comment: appreciate your help. This is a last minute issue for us so running against time :)

Comment: The main issue is that existing market app having widget. Now the case is that we are using 4.2 API for update as we have to use some features of 4.2

now when we install the market app and add the widget and when we update the app then the widget gets removed from the home screen and user have to manually add again the widget.

Is something changed in 4.2 SDK?

There are few devices i.e. LG 2.2 OS , Samsung Galaxy S3, Note 2 on which our app successfully updating the existing widget and on the few devices its removing the widget from the screen.